# vs code not support win11? bash: powershell: command not found

Tags: powershell, ssh, vscode-extensions

Can't connect to my college server after upgrading my pc to win11.
It's strange because I can use vs-code connect to it on my Macbook but not on my window desktop anymore. Not sure why it only happening on my desktop.

```
[00:37:42.740] > bash: powershell: command not found
[00:37:44.041] "install" terminal command done
[00:37:44.042] Install terminal quit with output: bash: powershell: command not found
[00:37:44.042] Received install output: bash: powershell: command not found
[00:37:44.042] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[00:37:44.042] Resolver error: Error:
at g.Create (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:585222)
at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:583874)
at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:681023)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:643908
at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:647224)
at async t.resolve (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:644958)
at async c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:726917
[00:37:44.045] ------

[00:37:44.109] ------

[00:37:44.109] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+access.engr.oregonstate.edu", attempt 2, (Reconnection)
[00:37:44.110] SSH Resolver called for host: access.engr.oregonstate.edu
[00:37:44.110] Setting up SSH remote "access.engr.oregonstate.edu"
[00:37:44.111] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[00:37:44.113] Install and start server if needed
[00:37:48.982] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[00:37:48.982] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceled
at g.Canceled (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:585418)
at c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:643820
at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:647224)
at async t.resolve (c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:644958)
at async c:\Users\kk3kk.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:726917
[00:37:48.983] ------

[00:37:48.984] ------

[00:37:48.984] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+access.engr.oregonstate.edu", attempt 3, (Reconnection)
[00:37:48.985] SSH Resolver called for host: access.engr.oregonstate.edu
[00:37:48.985] Setting up SSH remote "access.engr.oregonstate.edu"
[00:37:48.986] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[00:37:48.988] Install and start server if needed
```

Comment: The environmental PATH is doesn't include location where powershell is located.  From cmd >PATH  My machine has C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\  Maybe the version changed.

Comment: @jdweng what should I do to change the environmental path ? I’m new to use VS code, sorry:(

Comment: Press the windows Start button (white icon on bottom left of screen). Can be configured to any corner of monitor). Type Environmental.  Click on Edit the System Environmental Variables.  Then go to Advance Tab, Environmental Variables.  They are in both System and User views.   The two get concatenated.

Comment: it shows C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ like yours

Comment: Where is the powershell executable located on your machine?  It is not in the v1.0 folder or you do not have permission to execute the file.